# Fetch Column names from a joined mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `teams` and `top4`

`Teams` stores the name of all the teams and `top4` stores the teams a user thinks will be in the top4 by the end of the game.

`Top4` has 5 columns (`User_id`,`first(fk)`,`second`,`third`,`fourth`),

`Teams` has 2 columns(`Team_Id`,`Team_Name`).

Each column (`first`,`second`,`third`,`fourth`) in the top4 table has a foreign_key reference to the teams table(`Team_Id`)

I am trying to fetch the names of the teams whose ids are stored in the top4 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally do this with four joins:

```
select top4.*, t1.team_name, t2.team_name, t3.team_name, t4.team_name
from top4 join
     teams t1
     on top4.first = t1.team_id join
     teams t2
     on top4.second = t2.team_id join
     teams t3
     on top4.third = t3.team_id join
     teams t4
     on top4.fourth = t4.team_id;
```